# Chinese Sentiment Analysis Tools

Tags: open-source, software-development, nlp, language

I am doing a research study on some of the most recent Chinese Sentiment Analysis tools. My purpose is to evaluate the analysis results of each tool on a set of sentences – I am looking for sentence-level analysis instead of document-level analysis. The set of sentences would be randomly selected from social networking sites, i.e. the sentences will most likely be colloquial. In particular, I am looking for tools (at least 4) with the following specifications:

- The analysis scale must have at least two values, i.e. positive or negative. (I believe this is true for all sentiment analysis tools...just in case)
- The tool could preferably obtain a sentiment score for any Chinese sentences, i.e. the dataset it uses is large enough to cover most of the commonly used words.
- The tool is preferably open-source.
- The tool is preferably an SDK or API.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is the combination of [python](http://python.org) and the natural language toolkit, ([nltk](http://nltk.org)).

The [book](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/) Bird, Steven, Edward Loper and Ewan Klein (2009), Natural Language Processing with Python. O’Reilly Media Inc. states in its opening chapter:

> Technologies based on NLP are becoming increasingly widespread. For
>   example, phones and handheld computers support predictive text and
>   handwriting recognition; web search engines give access to information
>   locked up in unstructured text; machine translation allows us to
>   retrieve texts written in Chinese and read them in Spanish; text
>   analysis enables us to detect sentiment in tweets and blogs. By
>   providing more natural human-machine interfaces, and more
>   sophisticated access to stored information, language processing has
>   come to play a central role in the multilingual information society.

and a quick check on the sentiment analysis finds both positive and negative results.

*Please note that the latest version of NLTK has been made for python3 and that the book is in the process of being updated for that version.*

To cover your requirements one by one:

- The analysis scale must have at least two values, i.e. positive or negative. (I believe this is true for all sentiment analysis tools...just in case) - **Yes**
- The tool could preferably obtain a sentiment score for any Chinese sentences, i.e. the dataset it uses is large enough to cover most of the commonly used words. - **Yes** *but you may have to locate a good corpus for this a good starting point is [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/sinica_treebank.html).*
- The tool is preferably open-source.  - **Yes completely**
- The tool is preferably an SDK or API. - **Yes**

Comment: Thank you for sharing! But I thought the Python NLTK does not support Chinese? I have just used it half a year ago, unless it is recently updated to support Chinese analysis.

Comment: @ThomasHsieh take a look at http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/sinica_treebank.html